# Asynchronous duplication request with nginx

Tags: nginx, lua

How I can duplicate (or create and send) a request with the nginx web server. I can't use `post_action`, because it is a synchronous method. Also, I compiled nginx with Lua support, but if I try to use `http.request` with `ngx.thread.spawn` or `coroutine`, I find the request has been executed synchronously. How do I solve this?

```
location ~ /(.*)\.jpg {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6081;
    access_by_lua_file '/var/m-system/stats.lua';
}
```

Lua script (with `coroutine`):

```lua
local http = require "socket.http"
local co = coroutine.create(function()
        http.request("http://10.10.1.1:81/log?action=view")
    end
)
coroutine.resume(co)
```

Comment: Go thorugh: https://docs.apitools.com/blog/2014/09/12/light-threads-and-asynchronous-http-calls-in-nginx.html

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Interesting that you say `post_action` is synchronous. This example (https://github.com/lebinh/nginx-conf#sub-request-upon-completion) suggests it's happening asynchronously in the background. Is that example doing something differently, or is it plain wrong?

Comment: from local testing by putting a loop in a lua block in post_action I am seeing the post_actoin request execute sychronously and blocking the original request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ngx.thread.spawn not working, only this code worked:

```lua
access_by_lua '
    local socket = require "socket"
    local conn = socket.tcp()
    conn:connect("10.10.1.1", 2015)
    conn:send("GET /lua_async HTTP/1.1\\n\\n")
    conn:close()
';
```